# Combining multiple confidence intervals

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Suppose that we have 10 90% confidence intervals resulting from 10 large samples showing the percentage of 3rd-graders who don't know how to sum. Means, sample sizes and other statistical data are not given.

(1.10, 1.12)
(1.01, 1.04)
(1.01, 1.15)
(1.11, 1.12)
(1.03, 1.04)
(1.04, 1.07)
(1.05, 1.20)
(1.08, 1.17)
(1.09, 1.12)
(1.13, 1.25)

Where does the true percentage lie in the population?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

These ten CIs may be of the form $\hat p \pm 1.645\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$ where $\hat p = x/n$ for $x$ arithmetic deficient students in $n.$
Taking 'percentages' into account, the first CI is $(0.0110, 0.0112).$
That allows you to solve (approximately) for $x$ and $n$ of the first of ten groups.

Combine the ten $x$;s and $n$'s, assuming no overlapping of groups.
Then make a 90% CI for the combined data to estimate the true population
proportion of such students, and convert it to a percentage.